# Select Partition Column from Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have multiple tables that are timestamp partitioned over a column that I've specified. Unfortunately, the names of the columns are different and the tables are too large/expensive to replay just for a column name change. Is there a way to reference the partitioned column?

For example, if I had two tables and the first one was partitioned over col A and the second was partitioned over col B, is there a way to do: SELECT max(PARTITIONED_COLUMN) FROM Table_A, Table_B

Comment: Could you provide an example with some dummy data so, I can reproduce what you are trying to do?

Comment: Hey Alexandre. Let's say I have 3 tables: Table A, B, and C. Each table is timestamp partitioned; table A is partitioned by a column named time_A, table B by a column named time_B, and table C by time_C. Each of these timestamp partitions are in the same format, but are named differently in each table's schema. I want to run a query that outputs the max timestamp value from each of the 3 tables, meaning max(time_A) FROM Table A, max(time_B) FROM Table B, and max(time_C) FROM Table C.

Comment: Dummy data: Table A is partitioned over time_A. Values from time_A are as follows: 2020-01-09 19:48:34 UTC, 2019-05-09 19:48:34 UTC, 2019-08-09 13:48:34 UTC. max(time_A) would return 2020-01-09 19:48:34 UTC. Similar situation for Tables B, C, and so on. I want to avoid having to list all specific columns partitioned by (time_A, time_B, etc...) because I have a lot of tables. Is there a way to simply call "partitioned column"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, let's say the column of Table A you want to change is wrong_name.

```
SELECT 
   coalesce(A.col1, B.col1) as col1 
FROM 
  Table A, Table B
WHERE **...;
```

For your second question - how to reference the partition column see:

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#integer_range
- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#dt_compare
- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#query_jobs

Comment: Hey Rachel, that makes a lot of sense, however, I was looking for a way to reference the specific partitioned column regardless of table. In my specific case, I have a lot of tables, and it would be helpful to call PARTION_COL instead of listing A.part_col, B.part_col, C.part_col, etc... Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I see grouping the parts of the table under one partition. You mention a cost for altering tables, would creating a new table with all the parts be too costly? Would clustering these column partitions be helpful? https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/bigquery-configs

Comment: Unfortunately, creating a new table with all the subtables would be too costly and create inconsistency in our architecture. Clustering is something we're considering for another purpose, however, it's not advantageous here. In the current problem, we have a bunch of tables that are all partitioned over a timestamp (same format). That being said, the name isn't consistent between most of the tables. Based on our conversation, it doesn't seem like there's a way to call "the partitioned by column" without explicitly writing out its name, right?

Comment: Seems that way.

Answer (score 0):

After carefully reading you comments about you dummy data and what you expected. i can suggest you to use the pseudo column ***_PARTITIONTIME***. According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables):

> When you create an ingestion-time partitioned table, two pseudo
>   columns are added to the table: a _PARTITIONTIME pseudo column and a
>   _PARTITIONDATE pseudo column. The _PARTITIONTIME pseudo column contains a date-based timestamp for data that is loaded into the
>   table. The _PARTITIONDATE pseudo column contains a date
>   representation. Both pseudo column names are reserved, which means
>   that you cannot create a column with either name in any of your
>   tables.

Therefore you can select the ***MAX(_PARTITIONTIME)*** for each table, using the pseudo column. I used a public dataset to show how it works.

First I wrote my results to an ingestion-time partitioned table:

```
bq query \
--destination_table your_project:your_dataset.partitioned_table \
--time_partitioning_type=DAY \
--use_legacy_sql=false \
'SELECT
   name,
   number
 FROM
   `bigquery-public-data`.usa_names.usa_1910_current
 WHERE
   gender = "M"
 ORDER BY
   number DESC'
```

Then in the console, I used the created time partitioned table to  select the *MAX(_PARTITIONTIME)*.

```
SELECT
  MAX(_PARTITIONTIME) AS max_part_date
FROM
  `your_project.your_dataset.partitioned_table`
WHERE
  DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = "2020-01-16"
LIMIT
  1000
```

And the output:

[image]

I hope it helps.